# Docker x NodeJS - Issue with node_modules

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules

I'm a web developer who currently is working on a next.js project (it's just a framework to SSR ReactJS). I'm using Docker config on this project and I discovered an issue when I add/remove dependencies. When I add a dependency, build my project and up it with docker-compose, my new dependency isn't added to my Docker image. I have to clean my docker system with `docker system prune` to reset everything then I could build and up my project. After that, my dependency is added to my Docker container.

I use `Dockerfile` to configure my image and different `docker-compose` files to set different configurations depending on my environments. Here is my configuration:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.13.0-alpine

# SET environment variables
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.13.0
ENV YARN_VERSION 1.12.3

# Install Yarn
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-yarn curl \
  && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
  && ln -snf /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -snf /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && apk del .build-deps-yarn

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /website
WORKDIR /website
ADD package*.json /website

# Install app dependencies 
RUN yarn install

# Build source files
COPY . /website/
RUN yarn run build
```

**docker-compose.yml (dev env)**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: website
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3332:3332"
      - "9229:9229"
    volumes:
      - /website/node_modules/
      - .:/website
    command: yarn run dev 0.0.0.0 3000
    environment:
      SERVER_URL: https://XXXXXXX.com
```

**Here my commands to run my Docker environment:**

> docker-compose build --no-cache
>
> docker-compose up

I suppose that something is wrong in my Docker's configuration but I can't catch it. Do you have an idea to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your volumes right now are not set up to do what you intend to do. The current set below means that you are overriding the contents of your `website` directory in the container with your local `.` directory.

```
volumes:
  - /website/node_modules/
  - .:/website
```

I'm sure your intention is to map your local directory into the container first, and then override `node_modules` with the original contents of the image's node_modules directory, i.e. `/website/node_modules/`.

Changing the order of your volumes like below should solve the issue.

```
volumes:
  - .:/website
  - /website/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly telling Docker you want this behavior.  When you say:

```
volumes:
  - /website/node_modules/
```

You are telling Docker you don't want to use the `node_modules` directory that's baked into the image.  Instead, it should create an anonymous volume to hold the `node_modules` directory (which has some special behavior on its first use) and persist the data there, even if other characteristics like the underlying image change.

That means if you change your `package.json` and rebuild the image, Docker will keep using the volume version of your `node_modules` directory.  (Similarly, the bind mount of `.:/website` means everything else in the last half of your Dockerfile is essentially ignored.)

I would remove the `volumes:` block in this setup to respect the program that's being built in the image.  (I'd also suggest moving the `command:` to a `CMD` line in the `Dockerfile`.)  Develop and test your application without using Docker, and build and deploy an image once it's essentially working, but not before.